# Statistical criterion with zero probability of Type $1$ and Type $2$ errors

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I have heard that if one of the distributions is discrete (say Poisson for example) and another one is absolutely continuous (Gaussian as example) it is always possible to construct a statistical criterion, such that it has zero probability of Type $1$ and Type $2$ errors.

Can anybody show how it works?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.  In general, it is not possible to eliminate the possibility of making either a Type I or Type II error, let alone both.  The whole point of statistics is that there is *always* going to be some uncertainty---the best you can do is try to quantify that uncertainty.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, suppose that null-hypothesis is that our sample came from discrete distribution and the alternative one is that it came from absolutely continuous. So, the statement is false and it is not possible to construct a criterion with zero probabilities of Type I and Type II errors? This statement also seems non-intuitive for me, this is why I want to clarify it and ask somebody to show an example (if it may be true, of course).

Comment: Suppose you have unrounded data. If all observations are exactly integers, then the discrete model is a sure bet. If any of the observations is a non-integer, then the continuous model is a sure bet. // In reality, you have to round the data to _some_ number of decimal places, so it is with small $n$ it is _conceivable_ (very unlikely) that all continuous observations would happen to round to integers. (But the context of this question does not seem to anticipate practical application.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a random variable, $H_0: X \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and $H_1: X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. We can define an hypothesis test with the critical region $R=\{x \in \mathbb{R}: x \notin \mathbb{N}\}$. The type I error is the probability of rejection under $H_0$, that is, $P(R|H_0)=0$. This occurs, since under $H_0$, $X$ follows a Poisson distribution and can only be an integer. Also, the type II errors is the probability that you don't reject $H_0$ when it is false, that is, $P(R^c|H_1)=0$. This occurs because, under $H_1$, $X$ has a continuous distribution and $R^c=\mathbb{N}$.

The same type of result occurs whenever there exist two disjoint events, $A_0$ and $A_1$, such that $P(X \in A_0|H_0)=1$ and $P(X \in A_1|H_1)=1$. One can reject $H_0$ whenever $A_1$ occurs and the errors of type I and II will be $0$.